# Is it possible to sort with grouping by in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sorting, grouping

```
List<ManualInfo> manuals = manualRepository.manuals();
manuals.stream()
    .collect(
        groupingBy( // group 1
            ManualInfo::getLargeClass,
            groupingBy( // group 2
                ManualInfo::getMediumClass,
                groupingBy( //group 3
                    ManualInfo::getSmallClass,

                )
            )
        )
    );
```

In order to respond to the manual in a category structure (json), all manuals are retrieved from the database and then grouped. The categories are structured the way I want them to, but out of order.

I found out after a long time research that ordering before grouping does not work, and that ordering cannot be done after grouping.

As shown below, I recently learned how to group with order, can this be applied to category structure as well?

```
LinkedHashMap<String, List<ManualInfo>> collect = manuals.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(ManualInfo::getLargeClass, // group1
                        LinkedHashMap::new, // how can i do group2, group3....?
                        toList()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're fine with the initial order of elements in the list, then you need to use *three-args* version of [`groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.stream.Collector)) which allows to provide a `Supplier` *mapFactory* in place of **every** *two-args* grouping in your code.

And each of these collectors should specify `LinkedHashMap` as a desired accumulation type:

```
List<ManualInfo> manuals = manualRepository.manuals();
        
var resultingMap = manuals.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy( // group 1
        ManualInfo::getLargeClass,
        LinkedHashMap::new,
        Collectors.groupingBy( // group 2
            ManualInfo::getMediumClass,
            LinkedHashMap::new,
            Collectors.groupingBy( //group 3
                ManualInfo::getSmallClass,
                LinkedHashMap::new,
                Collectors.toList()
            )
        )
    ));
```

***Note** that it's mandatory to provide a downstream collecor as the last argument with this flavor of* `groupingBy()` *and for the first and the second collector the downstream would be the subsequent nested grouping, and for the last one we need to provide* `toList()` *as a downstream (which is used implicitly under the hood in one-arg version of* `groupingBy()`*).*

And in case if the ordering of data doesn't match your requirements, then you need to sort the elements before collecting the data.

Assuming that `ManualInfo` looks like that:

```
public class ManualInfo {
    private String largeClass;
    private String mediumClass;
    private String smallClass;
    
    // getters, constructors, etc.
}
```

And let's say you want the data to be sorted first by `largeClass`, then by `mediumClass`, and finally by `smallClass`. Then, using Java 8 `static` methods of the `Comparator` interface, we can define the following comparator (*you can any sorting criteria you need, it's just an example on how to build the Comparator*):

```
Comparator.comparing(ManualInfo::getLargeClass)
    .thenComparing(ManualInfo::getMediumClass)
    .thenComparing(ManualInfo::getSmallClass)
```

And the code might look like that:

```
var resultingMap = manuals.stream()
    .sorted( // imposing the required ordering
        Comparator.comparing(ManualInfo::getLargeClass)
            .thenComparing(ManualInfo::getMediumClass)
            .thenComparing(ManualInfo::getSmallClass)
    )
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy( // group 1
        ManualInfo::getLargeClass,
        LinkedHashMap::new,
        Collectors.groupingBy( // group 2
            ManualInfo::getMediumClass,
            LinkedHashMap::new,
            Collectors.groupingBy( //group 3
                ManualInfo::getSmallClass,
                LinkedHashMap::new,
                Collectors.toList()
            )
        )
    ));
```

There's another option of how to impose ordering. You can use [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html) as accumulation type.

But **note** that it would only work if the required ordering exactly **matches** the criteria of grouping, because `TreeMap` maintains sorted order based on keys.

```
var resultingMap = manuals.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy( // group 1
        ManualInfo::getLargeClass,
        TreeMap::new,
        Collectors.groupingBy( // group 2
            ManualInfo::getMediumClass,
            TreeMap::new,
            Collectors.groupingBy( //group 3
                ManualInfo::getSmallClass,
                TreeMap::new,
                Collectors.toList()
            )
        )
    ));
```